# Error while using Bootstrap 4 with Rails 6 Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-4, webpacker

I have a very simple Rails 6 application with jquery configured as follows:

config/webpack/environment.js :

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    jQuery: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

I am trying to use Bootstrap. However, I am not able to use any Bootstrap JS method with JQuery selector.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

// Error: Uncaught TypeError: $(…).tooltip is not a function
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! 
Thanks

---

### Solution

config/webpack/environment.js :

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1)

You're using `turbolinks`, so instead `document:ready` you should rely on `turbolinks:load` event

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
})
```

(2)

Don't use *minified* javascript libraries

```
// application.js
import "bootstrap"
```

```
// config/webpack/environment.js
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help!

Changing `jquery/dist/jquery.min` to `jquery` within `ProvidePlugin` did the trick!! It would be very informative if you can add why not to use minified javascript libraries with webpack. :)